# Sprint Galaxy S4. Javascript required random popup

Tags: notifications

I get a random popup on my S4.  "Javascript required" and then it gives me instructions to enable Java on various browsers. This error has nothing to do with me actively using a browser on the phone.

How do I cure this?  Thank you.

Comment: Any app you've recently installed, which could be connected to that? Could be some misconfigured ad-module or, might be, even some malicious code introduced with that.